# Access violation inside LoadLibrary() call

Tags: winapi, dll, labview, loadlibrary

I encounter an access violation when calling a DLL inside LabVIEW. Let's call the DLL "extcode.dll". I don't have its code, it comes from an external manufacturer.

Running it in Windbg, it stopped with the message:

```
(724.1200): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ntdll!RtlNewSecurityObjectWithMultipleInheritance+0x12a:
```

And call stack is:

```
ntdll!RtlNewSecurityObjectWithMultipleInheritance+0x12a
ntdll!MD5Final+0xedfc
ntdll!RtlFindClearBitsAndSet+0xdf4
ntdll!RtlFindClearBitsAndSet+0x3a8
ntdll!RtlFindClearBitsAndSet+0x4b9
ntdll!RtlCreateProcessParametersEx+0x829
ntdll!LdrLoadDll+0x9e
KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW+0x19c
KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExA+0x51
LabVIEW!ChangeVINameWrapper+0x36f5
LabVIEW!ChangeVINameWrapper+0x3970
LabVIEW!ExtFuncDynLibWrapper+0x211
```

Note that dependencies of extcode.dll are loaded before access violation.

The situation is random, but when it happens all subsequent tries lead to it.

The code is a simple LabVIEW function calling a function in the DLL, and prototype is super simple (`int function(void)`) so it cannot be an misconfiguration of the call parameters, nor pointer arithmetics. I checked every combination of calling conventions and error checking levels.

The DLL runs perfectly fine when called in other environments (.NET and C).

I found that `RtlFindClearBitsAndSet` is related to bit array manipulations

What does it make you think about? Do you think it is a problem in extcode.dll, LabVIEW, or Windows?

PS: I use LabVIEW 2010 64 bit, on Windows 7 64 bit (and extcode.dll is 64 bit). I didn't manage to reproduce it on 32 bit system.

**11/18 EDIT**

I ended up making a standalone exe that wraps the DLL; LabVIEW communicates with it through pipes. It works perfectly, but I stil don't understand why loading a DLL into LabVIEW can crash.

Answer (score 1):

If it works ok when called from C, you can quit working with Windbg because the DLL is probably ok. Something is wrong with how the DLL is being called, and once the DLL overwrites some of LabView's memory it is all over, even though it might take 1000 iterations before something actually goes kablooey.

First check your calling conventions, C or StdCall. C calling convention is the default and StdCall is almost certainly what you want. (Check the DLL header file.) LabView 2009 apparently did some auto-checking and fixing of calling conventions, but the switch to LLVM in LV 2010 has made this impossible; now it just tanks.

If it still tanks after changing this, check your calling arguments again. what you are passing, scalars or pointer data? You cannot access memory allocated by the DLL from LabView without doing some sneaky things, although you can allocate memory (i.e. byte array) in LabView and pass a pointer to it to the DLL for it to modify.

Also, if you are getting a pointer (such as a refnum) from an earlier call to DLL and returning it, check your pointer size. LabView's Call Library function now has a "pointer size integer" type, which generates the appropriately-sized type depending on whether it is invoked in 32-bit or 64-bit LabView. (It is always 64 bits on the wire, because that has to be defined at compile time.) The fact that your DLL works in 32 suggests this is a possibility.

Also keep in mind that C structs are often aligned by the (C) compiler. If you are passing a pointer to a struct made of a Uint8 and an UInt16, the C compiler will allocate 32 bits (or maybe even 64 bits) for this. You'll have to pad your struct (cluster) in LabView to make it match, or write a wrapper DLL to assemble the struct.

-Rob

Comment: Thanks for your answer: prototype is `int func(void)`, so it can't be a calling convention or argument pointer problem.

Comment: Maybe you should open a support case with NI. They are pretty good about helping with things like this.

Answer (score 1):

An access violation (0xc0000005) will also be reported if **DEP** (Data Execution Prevention) is enabled on your machine and disapproves of something your binary (EXE or DLL) is trying to do. **DEP** is usually off by default on Windows XP, but active on Windows Vista / Windows 7.

**DEP** is a hardware-supported security measure designed to prevent malicious code executing some bytes that previously were considered "just some data"; I've had a few run-ins with it, all of which required re-compiling the offending binaries with a recent version of Microsoft Visual Studio; this allows to you set a flag which defines whether or not your binary supports **DEP**.

Some useful resources:

- I found [this MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/10/understanding-data-execution-prevention-crashes-in-ie8.aspx)
  very helpful for gaining an
  understanding of what DEP is and does
- You might also want to consult t[his
  technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700810.aspx) on how to turn
  DEP on and off on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks Edward; I can't test if it was the problem since I worked around it by loading the DLL in a separate process and doing IPC calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to diagnose remotely, but here are a couple of ideas.

The fact that your function takes no arguments means that either the function is truly trivial, or there is some stored state in the dll that takes into account previous function calls.  Maybe the crash in this function is only an indicator, and you have a problem with a previous function call?  Is there an initilization routine you're not calling?

If you only have problem when using 64 bit labview, my first guess would be that there's a problem with the 64 bit version of the dll, but if you are sure you don't have any problem with the exact same calls when using the dll in other environments, I'm stumped.  One possibility is that you are using the wrong calling convention (stdcall vs. cdecl) in labview.

Have you tried importing the dll and header using the labview import wizard?  This might help avoid silly mistakes with the prototypes.

Comment: There's no init routine, it can work with this single function call. Tried labview import wizard, different calling convention, no success. Prototype is deadly simple (`int func(void)`) so it's not a pointer problem. I'm stumped too.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to try:  right click on the DLL call, choose configure and make sure you're running in the UI thread instead of any thread.  Sometimes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When working with git and cygwin under NTFS, i found that sometimes the executable bit is not set (or un-set during checkout or some file operations) - inside cygwin cd to the folder and do

```
chmod a+rwx *.dll
```

and check if it changes a thing (and check if you want it this way!). I found this question while searching for LoadLibrary() failing with GetLastError() returning 5 (not "0xc0000005" btw) and solved the issue with this chmod call.